# Angularjs can factory returning object contain another object or just functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have factory that contain inside some functions and object.
for example:

```
angular.module('app').factory('factory', function(){

    var that = this;

    that.a = function() {that.data = {'id': 100}}

    that.b = function(){ ** some code ***}

    return { a:that.a, b:that.b, data:that.data };

});
```

But, when i access to the function 'a' from outside the factory ('factory.a'),  and create the data object:

```
that.data = {'id': 100}
```

and then access to 'data' from outside ('factory.data') - data is undefined.

I have to return just functions in the returning object of factory?

Comment: There's a typo. Change `return { a:that.a, b:that,b, data:that.data };` to `return { a:that.a, b:that.b, data:that.data };`.

Comment: I know, this is just typo this is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`that.data` is undefined until you call `that.a()` at least once. To solve this, create `that.data` outside from `that.a` or call `that.a`:

```
angular.module('app').factory('factory', function(){

    var that = this;
    that.a = function() {that.data = {'id': 100}}

    that.b = function(){ ** some code ***}

    that.getData = function() { return that.data; }

    return { a:that.a, b:that.b, getData:that.getData };

});
```

By calling `factory.a(); console.log(factory.getData());` you're getting the correct value.

---

***EDIT:***
Added working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c3zvp48/5/) with getter getData()

Comment: If that solved your problem, accept my answer please :)

Comment: that's what i did - option B. first call to factory.a() and then factory.data but factory.data is still undefined.

Comment: Created a [working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c3zvp48/3/) with exactly that code.

Comment: But i don't call to - that.a() inside factory. just outside. like that:

Comment: factory.a(); console.log(factory.data);  (and the code is exactly like i wrote in the question)

Comment: Added a getter, solves the problem. See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c3zvp48/5/)

Comment: That what i thought.. Thanks!